# Are all your iotas moved to the new address when pressing "generate new address" in the light wallet?

Tags: wallet, address, address-reuse

When pressing "Generate new address", under "Receive", in the light wallet are all your IOTAs moved to this new address?

This is the scenario I am trying to grasp:
Let's say you sent IOTAs twice from the same address. The IOTAs on this address are now compromised. If you now press "Generate new address" will the IOTAs be moved to the new address, and thus be safe, or will all IOTAs that was received on a specific address remain there until they are manually sent to a new address (and thus still be compromised in the given scenario)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press the button "Generate new address", this is what happens:

- generate new private key from the seed
- generate address from the new private key
- send a 0-value transaction *to* the address

Your Iotas **remain on the old addresses**, where they were before.

If your old addresses are compromised for some reason, you can **send all your Iotas to the new address**.
(It is possible to send Iotas to yourself. You will see the transaction in your history but your balance won't change because you send Iotas from one of *your* addresses to another one of *your* addresses)